# Perl / Unix download pdf from website

Tags: perl, unix, pdf, web, download

post #2 :) don't worry I don't intend to count them all...

Is there an easy way to download a pdf file from a website using a perl or shell script?
If I have an url as such:
http://www.cs.middlebury.edu/~briggs/Courses/CS201-F12/js/js.pdf
Actually, i will have a cron job that will be running daily to download a pdf file from a website
any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look at `wget` or `curl`. Example: `wget <URL> -O <output file>`

Comment: Thanks wget works prefectly. However, searching on the web I read one should properly quit the website to avoid someone else taking control of your system. I am unable to find anything about that. Do you know how this works? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `LWP` set of modules has a cut-down version [`LWP::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aSimple) which allows this sort of thing to be done very simply.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple 'getstore';

my $resp = getstore('http://www.cs.middlebury.edu/~briggs/Courses/CS201-F12/js/js.pdf', 'js.pdf');
print  $resp, "\n";
```

The value of `$resp` is the HTTP status code and should normally be 200 for a successful operation.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your responses. I'll look up on these.